# Load an UIView from UIViewController inside storyboard doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am trying to load an `UIView` from an `UIViewController` inside my `Storyboard` without `segue`. I created the `UIViewcontroller`, layouted everything, connected it with the specific class and set a `Storyboard ID`. I also connected the elements to the `h.file`of my class and now I am looking for a way to initialize a `subview` of this `UIViewController` without a `segue`. I have been searching and found a lot of posts which loads the `UIViewController` this way:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    pointVC = (PointsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PointsViewController"];
```

Try to add the view like this, the view jumps to the next `UIViewController`:

```
pointVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:pointVC animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Adding it like `addChildViewController` also doesn't work:

```
[self addChildViewController:pointVC];
```

after initializing I try to add one of the `UIViews` inside the specific `UIViewController` to my actual View but it doesn't work. There doesn't happen anything if I just use the first two lines, the `UIViewController` object has no `UIViews` inside because `viewDidLoad` never will be called. Any ideas?

---

#### I also tried

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
pointVC = (PointsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PointsViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:pointVC];
[self.view addSubview:pointVC.viewPointsDialog];
[pointVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: did (pointVC != nil) after you get it from storyboard?

Comment: pointVC is not nil, but the elements are all nil because `viewDidLoad` will never be called

Comment: @亚历山大 did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
[self.view addSubview:pointVC.view];
```

instead of

```
[self.view addSubview:pointVC.viewPointsDialog];
```

So final working code should look like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
pointVC = (PointsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PointsViewController"];
[self addChildViewController:pointVC];
[self.view addSubview:pointVC.view];
[pointVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

You can use setFrame on pointVC.view to position it properly.

Comment: But `viewPointsDialog` is an `UIView` inside my second `UIViewController`. And I don't want to get the whole `UIView` of `pointsVC`, just the `UIView` I have created inside it

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you initialise a `UIViewController` from storyboard using

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    pointVC = (PointsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PointsViewController"];
```

this will only initialise the view controller, sort of `alloc/init` method. So if you try to add a view as a subview of the view controller's view, at this moment, it won't work because the view controller's view is not loaded yet. You have to `push/present/addChild` the view controller first and after that add the subview.

Second, if you had created segues just use the `performSegueWithIdentifier:` method to push/present the view controller (there is modal segue), and in your pushed/presented view controller `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear` methods you can add the subivew (don't do it in `viewDidLoad` because the frame of the view might not be properly set yet).

Third, if you are using autolayout, you might have to check the constraints and make sure to disable the conversion from springs to autolayout, because `addSubview` will enable that conversion.

Comment: To perform segues is no problem, I know how to use them. I just wanted to create a second `UIViewController` so I don't mess one `UIViewController` with many different `UIViews`. I also added the `UIViewController` with `addChildViewController` like I wrote in my post but this doesn't call any of the methods like `viewDidLoad` `viewDidAppear` `viewWillAppear`

Comment: If you add the controller with `addChildViewController` you have to call `didMoveToParentViewController` so that the `viewDidLoad` is called.

Comment: I tried to add this, you can see how the code looks like, I edited my post at the top. But the ui elements still doesn't get initialized

Answer (score 0):

The reason the the elements are all nil is that the elements will be loaded ONLY after the view is to be displayed. You can force it to load the elements. Here is what has worked for me:

```
UIViewController *vC = 
 [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ViewControllers" 
                            bundle:nil] 
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];`  
vC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
```

You can then display or show the view:

```
[self presentViewController:vC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I had to do this for any view controller that was loaded from storyboard. You will not need to do this if the view controller is loaded from nib or xib file.