# How to pass data to view controller being instantiated from UIStoryboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I instantiate and push my `UIViewController` using the following code:

```
RIYNetworkGameViewController *ngvc = 
      [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] 
       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"networkGame"];
ngvc.food = 42;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ngvc animated:YES];
```

Instead of assigning the value 42 to the property after instantiating it, is there a way to pass in the value so that it can be used during instantiation? I use only `storyboards`, and don't have any `nib` files, so I'm not sure what methods are called to instantiate the `UIViewController`.

EDIT: I create and present an SKScene in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, so I need to have the data before `viewWillLayoutSubviews` is called.

Comment: Why do you push the controller manually when you are using Storyboards?

Comment: This particular view controller is created in response to a game center match being created, so I have to create the controller at run time. After Game Center creates a match, a delegate method is called that creates the view controller. I'm not sure there is a way to do this with a storyboard, is there ?

Comment: Then why you don't use UIStoryboardSegue's?

Comment: you can use userdefault or some global reference instance variable. But its not a standard code.

Comment: I want to avoid using a global reference variable or user default. @Akki - I'm new to using Storyboards / IB. How is UIStoryboardSegue better than what I am doing now?

Comment: I tried to get an `UIView` from a `UIViewController` inside the storyboard. Maybe you can solve it with the help I got. I'm still looking for a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046810/load-an-uiview-from-uiviewcontroller-inside-storyboard-doesnt-work

Comment: @亚历山大 I'm not trying to add views - I just want to pass data in. I can already do this with my above code, but what I really want to do is pass it into whatever "init" method is called by the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your data in `- prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *identifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueName"]) {
        YourControllerClass *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
        [controller setPassingData:passingData]
    }
}
```

To using this, call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueName" sender:sender]` instead of `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]`.

Comment: The prepareForSegue method doesn't take any parameters - how do I pass my objects to it? I was trying to avoid using some kind of global. Isn't this just like what I am doing, except you can see it storyboard ? (I'm asking because I am new. Please don't mind.) How is this better than what I am doing?

Comment: I tried this - Perhaps I misunderstood, because it doesn't work for me. If I do ` RIYNetworkGameViewController * controller = [segue destinationViewController]; controller.food = 43;` when the segue completes, food = 0; In my earlier code, the assignment was persistent.

Comment: @John, it's very strange, because it always works fine for me. You can pass desired parameter to `-prepareForSegue:` thru sender. Here working example from my current project:
`NSString *identifier = [segue identifier]; if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"photoControllerSegue"]) { SUGalleryViewController *gallery = [segue destinationViewController]; [gallery setPhotoSource:self.user]; UIGestureRecognizer *gr = (UIGestureRecognizer*)sender; [gallery setStartingIndex:(gr.view ? gr.view.tag - 1 : 0)];`
    }`

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Instead of using "." I also tried using `setFood:42` but after the controller is loaded the value of food is 0.

Comment: It works - it was my fault! I made a typo in the identifier. But I don't see how this solves my problem. (I still can't pass an object into init etc before the controller is instantiated). I still have to let the controller instantiate and then set a property.

Comment: @John, `controller` in `-prepareForSegue:` is ALREADY instantiated. You can access to your data in `-loadView` or `-viewDidLoad` and use it as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, your view controller is instanciated but not loaded !

You should give init only info necessary for initialization.
For example, if "food" is an initializing related data, you shoud create a new designated initializer like `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"networkGame" andFood:42`
(in this case, call `[super init]` in it's implementation).

If your passing data issue is not about initializing why would you use another way than `ngvc.food = 42;` to pass data ? This is the good practice.

Comment: I want to pass data that could be used to instantiate it - If I could pass data to however the view controller is being initialised, it could be better.

Comment: So you should create a new designated initialiser like
`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"networkGame" andFood:42`
Don't forget to call `[super init]` in it's implementation.
Is that answers your question?

Comment: I don't think so - modifying UIStoryboard would let me pass data to UIStoryboard, but I don't know how UIStoryboard would pass that data to whatever init method is being called on my view controller.

Comment: The storyboard is your MVC's view, views sould not own their data, it should be managed by the view controller. So i'm not sure to get what you want to do here.

In another comment you said you instanciate the view in a game center related delegate, you could use `preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifierSetInTheStoryboardInspector"` method and then implement this method to configure your destinqtion view controller (this method will be used for any segue in the depart view, so inside you should check the identifier)

Can you give more specific details about what you're doing & your constraints?

Comment: You can then implement `viewDidLoad` in the destination view controller to do whatever you want with food's value beign previously set in `prepareForSegue:` method (`ngvc.food = 42;`) which is executed when you call `preformSegueWithIdentifier` (which you should not implement despite of what I said in the previous comment, I meant `prepareForSegue:` sorry)